If $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, then there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\alpha^n \in \mathbb Q$.
I wish to disprove the following proposition: If $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, then there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\alpha^n \in \mathbb Q$.
I'm trying to give a counterexample with $\alpha=\sqrt2+\sqrt3$.
I've already shown that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$ and that its minimal polynomial is $$ p(x)=x^4-10x^2+1$$ Now I wish to come up with a contradiction, and so far I've tried taking two different approaches:

Suppose there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\alpha ^n \in \mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ is a field, $\alpha ^n \in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$, and since $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=4$, this means that $\alpha ^n=a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2+d\alpha^3$ for some $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb Q$. Expanding each $\alpha^i$ in this sum, we get that $\alpha^n$ is a linear combination of $1, \sqrt2, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 6$. More specifically:
$$ \alpha^n = a+5c+(b+11d)\sqrt 2+(b+9d) \sqrt 3+2c \sqrt 6$$ Now I'm not sure how to proceed - I want to say that this implies $b=c=d=0$, but then I just get $\alpha^n=a$ which does nothing.
Using the Binomial Theorem, we get that $$ \alpha^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {{n}\choose{k}} \sqrt{2^{n-k}3^k}$$Again, not sure how to proceed. I struggle with showing "formally" that this implies that $\alpha^n$ is a combination of irrationals, thus irrational.

I also feel like I'm missing some other approach involving other extension field theorems, but I'm not sure.

Yeah, strictly speaking your post is a duplicate. Still, it seems to me that your proposed counterexample and its treatment by @Charvaka is of interest, so I hope it gets re-opened.

A related topic is that an algebraic integer, such as any natural power of algebra integer $\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 3$ would be, is rational only if it is actually an integer.

For simplicity, I would suggest using the sum of an integer and an irrational instead; for instance, $1+\sqrt{2}$.
This is an algebraic number and its minimal polynomial is $$p(x)=x^2-2x-1$$
Now, $$\begin{align}(1+\sqrt{2})^n&=1+n\sqrt{2}+{n\choose 2}2+{n\choose 3}\sqrt{2}^3+{n\choose 4}\sqrt{2}^4+\cdots\\&=1+n\sqrt{2}+n(n-1)+2{n\choose 3}\sqrt{2}+4{n \choose 4}+\cdots\\&=a+b\sqrt{2}, \,\, a,b\in\mathbb{Q}, \,\, b\neq 0\end{align}$$
As $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, we have $(1+\sqrt{2})^n=a+b\sqrt{2}$ is too, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
